# xulrunner tab close button

Tags: xul, xulrunner

I have an xul window with a tab box.  The tab and tappanel elements are generated as needed in Javascript.

I want the tabs to have a close button.  The docs for the 'tabs' tag talks about a 'closebutton' attribute buts says it is no longer supported.

I am trying to create content inside the tab.  Right now it contains two label tags.  The first is the actual tab label and the second is a red X (actually unicode \u2716).  It displays fine but I cannot seem to get an event to fire when the X is clicked.

I have tried using the onclick attribute and closebutton.addEventListener('click').

I also tried using a toolbarbutton instead of a label.  It displays the X but does not draw the button around it when the mouse hovers.  Most importantly I cannot get the button event to fire.

Comment: I tried figuring this out but I am really puzzled. It isn't only that `<tab>` children don't receive mouse events - they also cannot be found via `document.elementFromPoint()`. This has something to do with the XBL binding applied (the craziness stops if the binding is removed) but that binding is really minimal and shouldn't have any such impact.